# Powershell on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, powershell

Should I be worried that whenever I start my computer a tab opens and on this tab it is a blue screen with a little white flashing line as if I were going to type something and it says at the top,"C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" This started yesterday and I don't know what to do because I am bad with computers and have never seen this before.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows 7 Powershell](https://superuser.com/questions/1551784/windows-7-powershell)