# Windows 7 Powershell

Tags: windows-7, windows, powershell

I asked this same question on my original account that I no longer have access to. Yesterday when I turned on my computer a tab opened that is just a blue screen called

> C\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe

I got an answer saying to disable it from startup which did not work. I got a comment that said I probably installed something that wants to run a script at startup but it is unknown is it is malicious or not due to lack of information. I got another comment saying to run a program to tell me the process and copy and paste it so here is that:

> "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"

I need to know if I should be worried about this happening every time I start my computer or if I will be fine and a solution to get rid of it would be very helpful.

Comment: You likely installed software that is attempting to automatically run a script at Startup.  We won't be able to determine if it it's malicious given the lack of information.

Comment: Is there anything I should be looking out for to make sure it isn't malicious or is there anything I could find to give better information?

Comment: Install [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) and drag its bull's-eye over the window. It will find the process. Double-click the process and copy here its full command line. (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: @harrymc sorry about the wait and thank you for helping

Comment: That one seems probably to be [malware](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/577171/powershellexe-script-running/) thing. You should run an antivirus on your computer asap but you must to run it from a USB stick. I recommend you do create a [Kaspersky USB stick](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3qptjtiRcJ0).

Comment: Merged the old question with this one.

Answer (score 1):

That one seems probably to be **[malware](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/577171/powershellexe-script-running/)** thing. You should run an **antivirus** on your computer asap but you must to run it from a **USB stick**. I recommend you do create a **[Kaspersky USB stick](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3qptjtiRcJ0)**.

References:

- [PowerShell.exe Removal help](https://forums.malwarebytes.com/topic/240863-powershellexe-removal-help/)
- [powershell.exe script running](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/577171/powershellexe-script-running/)

Answer (score -2):

Just klick on the Start button, type msconfig and hit enter.

Then take a look at the fifth TAB called Startup or System Start or something like that (mine is german so it does not match), remove the Powershell entry and you are good to go again.

Comment: Who said that his computer is not starting? As I have understood it boots, Windows is loading, Desktop is there and a Window pops up with Powershell. There is no mention that he got Powershell access ONLY smart###

Comment: and just by the way, windows 7 is outdated since February 2020